# How can i display the Blood group in UITextField if user clicks the UIPickerview

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uipickerview

Wish you happy new year to all iOS developers.I want to display Blood group in `UITextfield`.
So I should took `UIPickerview` and append the Blood group list.My requirement is if user hit the `UITextfiled` the `UIPickerview` will be displayed and user select the blood group and it will reflect the blood group item in `UITextfield`.I am trying to do this functionality. But I have got some problem to display blood group value in `UITextfield`.The problem is for example if I click the A-ve blood group this will be displayed as it is in `UITextfield`.But if i click the A+ve group it will display like A ve instead of A+ve in `UITextfield`. This is my problem.Any body please help me. Thanks in advance.

The given below is my code.

```
//Bloodgroupviewcontroller.m

arrChooseServices=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"A+ve",@"A-ve",@"B+ve",@"B-ve",@"AB+ve",@"AB-ve",@"O+ve",@"O-ve", nil];

bloodGroup=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 200, 120, 20)];

bloodGroup.borderStyle=UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;

bloodGroup.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

bloodGroup.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.662745 green:0.662745 blue:0.662745 alpha:0.5];

[bloodGroup setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

bloodGroup.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];

bloodGroup.contentVerticalAlignment=UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;

bloodGroup.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;

bloodGroup.delegate=self;

bloodGroup.inputView=self.chooseServicePicker;

bloodGroup.inputAccessoryView=self.accessoryView;

[self.view addSubview:bloodGroup];


-(UIPickerView *)chooseServicePicker
{
   if(chooseServicePicker==nil)
   {

       chooseServicePicker=[[UIPickerView alloc]init];

       chooseServicePicker.delegate=self;

       chooseServicePicker.dataSource=self;

       chooseServicePicker.showsSelectionIndicator=YES;

     }
     return chooseServicePicker;
 }


 -(UIToolbar *)accessoryView
 {

      if ( accessoryView == nil )
      {
            accessoryView = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 30)];

             UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]  initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(onBloodGroupSelection)];

             UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(cancel)];

             accessoryView.items=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:doneButton,cancelButton, nil];
                 }
           return accessoryView;
      }


- (void)onBloodGroupSelection
{
    NSInteger row = [self.chooseServicePicker selectedRowInComponent:0];
    bloodGroup.text=[arrChooseServices objectAtIndex:row];
    [bloodGroup resignFirstResponder];
 }
```

Comment: did you NSLog your array and selected value?

Comment: Is it working with B+ve?

Comment: what is `NSLog` for `[arrChooseServices objectAtIndex:row];` ?

Comment: No brother.only display -ve blood group display proper way.But positive blood group values display like A ve, B ve,O ve like this.

Comment: I tested your code with `UILabel` and its working fine !

Comment: I tested the code too, it is working fine.

Comment: hi friends, i am using this blood group textfield in User profile page.My app requirement is updated profile page creation.If i edit the blood group textfield and select the some blood group.And after that i click the Done button the blood group will be updated.But "+" signs will not be displayed.IF i click the -ve blood group it will displayed as it is.

Answer (score 2):

About the `+` not displaying, I tested your code and it is working fine for me. I had to change the `[bloodGroup setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];` to `[bloodGroup setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];` to make the `UITextField` clickable. Still, try adding

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow: (NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
     bloodGroup.text = [arrChooseServices objectAtIndex:row] ;
}
```

to your code to make the `UITextField` change text when the `UIPickerView` is tapped.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
Add this method and other delegate method to ur class

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow: (NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    yourtextfield.text = [yourdataarray objectAtIndex:row] ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Take a string globally as "selectedString"

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{      
 selectedString = yourdataarray[row];                                                                  
}

-(void)onBloodGroupSelection
 {
 bloodGroup.text= selectedString;
 [self.view endEditing:YES];
 }
```